# Why is wye-wye connection rarely used?

Tags: ac, three-phase, electric-machine

Fitzgerald's Electric Machinery book explains the following on chapter 2.7:

> ...
>
> The delta-delta connection has the advantage that one transformer can
> be removed for repair or maintenance while the remaining two continue
> to function as a three-phase bank with the rating reduced to 58
> percent of that of the original bank; this is known as the open-delta,
> or V, connection. The Y - Y connection is seldom used because of
> difficulties with exciting-current phenomena. (footnote 5)
>
> (footnote 5): Because there is no neutral connection to carry
> harmonics of the exciting current, harmonic voltages are produced
> which significantly distort the transformer voltages

I don't understand how there is "no neutral connection" in the Y-Y system, as it is the only system where both primary and secondary do have the neutral connection. What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't need a neutral for a balanced load and balanced supply but, a Y-Y transformer has serious problems in producing a balanced output on light loads. That's why you don't see this configuration used in transformers.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you, so the book's explanation is incorrect? Also, can you explain or direct me to a source that explains (mathematically) why the Y-Y transformer would struggle providing balanced output on light loads?

Comment: I don't know of a book that explains this but also, I can't say that the quote above is incorrect; for me, any primary coil impedance imbalances will produce significant output voltage imbalances on light loads due to the star formation and, that is why a Y primary is never used without significant reasons.